# SDCard installation: Raspbian zip doesn't unzip on Mac

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, software-installation

I am struggling to install Raspbian to an SDCard from my Mac.

Every documentation mentions `.img` files, though it's unclear about how to create those from the zip file provided online.

When trying to unzip the file from GUI I get an error (a stranger intermediate file is created), through command line the error is different (it doesn't matter if the result is piped or not):

```
$ unzip -p 2017-02-16-raspbian-jessie.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4096
warning [2017-02-16-raspbian-jessie.zip]:  76 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [2017-02-16-raspbian-jessie.zip]:  reported length of central directory is
  -76 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1
  zipfile?).  Compensating...

note:  didn't find end-of-central-dir signature at end of central dir.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000017 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

I have checked the SHA1 sum and it is correct, so the archive is not corrupted.

- Mac OS X El Capitan `10.11.6`
- UnZip `5.52 of 28 February 2005`: god this looks old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unzip` on macOS has problems handling files larger than 4 GB.

Use a different program: `ditto`, `tar`, `funzip`, for example:

```
funzip 2017-02-16-raspbian-jessie.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4096
```

Comment: I won't comment on my feeling about what Apple does (or doesn't do) here. But thanks a lot!

Comment: In most of such cases in macOS it's not the fault of Apple, but the licensing of a particular program which might limit the possibility for distribution by other parties (and as new licenses were introduced, copyright holders often changed the licensing at some version). Although I don't know if this is the reason for outdated UnZip in macOS (supposedly it's BSD-licensed).

Comment: Interesting remark